# Add an Entry in a Table with Identity Column on a Microsoft DB with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Like the title says, I have a problem with the Entity Framework...

I want to insert data into my DB with the EF on a table with a identity primary key column...

But when I create my object without an ID like this...

```
var p= new T_Person() { Name = "Test", Gender='m', Age=19 };
```

and try to add it to my DB like this...

```
DbContext.T_Person.Add(p); DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I always get an error with the message, that I need to set the IDENTITY INSERT to ON when I want to add a entry to my table, because the PersonID automatically has the value 0...

**EDIT 1:**
I work with Model First Approach and the person class is auto generated like this...

```
namespace Model 
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class T_Person
    {
        public T_Person()
        {
            ...
        }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public char Gender{ get; set; }
        public int Age{ get; set; }
        ...
```

if I added the Attribute with DatabaseGenerated like this:

```
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
```

the next question is how can I get the generated value for my ID Property of my Person Object? I know that I can get the current Identity value with the "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('T_Person')" SQL Command, but when I try to find a person with the ID value like:

```
var addedPerson = ctx.T_Person.FirstOrDefault(pe => pe.PersonID == id);
```

id is the attribute with the value of the SQL Command...

**EDIT 2:**

the save method looks like this:

```
using (var transaction = DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    ObservableCollection<T_PersonContakt> pContacts = new ObservableCollection<T_PersonContakt>();

    try
    {
         var p= new T_Person() { Name = "Test", Gender='m', Age=19 };
         ctx.T_Person.Add(pers);
         ctx.SaveChanges();

         foreach (var contact in PersonContacts)
         {
              pContacts.Add(new T_PersonKontakt()
              {
                   TypeID = contact.TypeID,
                   Priority = contact.Priority,
                   PersonID = id, // HERE I NEED THE ID OF THE INSERTED PERSON
                   Value = contact.Value
               });
          }
          ctx.SaveChanges();
          ctx.T_Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonID == id).T_PersonContakt = pContacts;

         ctx.SaveChanges();
         transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         transaction.Rollback();
     }
 }
```

**EDIT 3**:

Like I said in EDIT 2, my attempt would be to get the current value of the identity with a scalar SQL Command, but I don't know if this is secure because the application is used by more than one user.

So i don't know if there would be a problem if two users try to insert a person at the same time...

Comment: I assume the discrepancy between `var person` and `.Add(p)` is just a typo. Is this model first approach?

Comment: How is `Person` defined? Specifically is the `PersonID` property defined as database generated?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `Person` class?

Comment: As Richard alluded to, you probably need this attribute added to your `PersonID` field: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: Yes, it is first model approach and the class is auto generated :)
I will try to define it as database generated and tell you if it works!

Comment: Inserting a person works fine with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute, but i edited the question  because i also need to know the generated value for my id :)